# How to add slot in html parameters?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In my Vue.js component I need to use slot in a parameter but my attempts of this does not work. Is there some way how to do this?

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'test': {
            template: `
            <iframe width="300px" height="200px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<slot></slot>"></iframe>
            `
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Why don't you use props?

Comment: That is not what slots are used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slots are used for inserting html you need props
Try this it'll work

```
 components: {
    test:{
      template:'<iframe width="300px" height="200px" :src="url"></iframe>',
     props: ['url'],
    }
 }
```

and pass your url from parent

```
<test url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-rCZNFARSfQ" />
```